# What do you call a modifier placed at the beginning of a sentence for dramatic effect?

Tags: word-order, modifiers

For example, take two of Mignon McLaughlin's aphorisms:

"For the happiest life, rigorously plan your days, and leave your nights open to chance."

"No matter how brilliantly an idea is stated, we will not really be moved unless we have already half thought of it ourselves."

Neither "For the happiest life" nor "No matter how brilliantly an idea is stated" is a dangling modifier. But both feel like cliff-hangers.

Is there a term, or are there terms, for this (linguistic and/or colloquial)?

Answer (score 1):

From [grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/irregularverbs/a/Notes-On-Do.htm)...

> In English grammar, **fronting** refers to any construction in which a word group that customarily follows the verb is placed at the beginning of a sentence.
>   Also called **front-focus** or **preposing**.

In OP's two examples, the "primary" verb clauses are ***leave*** [your nights open to chance] and ***will*** [not really be moved] The "fronted" clauses add further information about what those verbs refer to, but when presented in that order it does mean the reader has to temporarily bear in mind that he hasn't yet reached the "syntactic centre" of the utterance.

It's a stylistic device which often has the effect of drawing *attention* to the fronted clause, but sometimes (particularly in *longer* constructions) it can result in confusing sentences.

Comment: My favorite is Gibbs's "Backward ran sentences till reeled the mind."

Comment: @Airymouse: Wow! That's a toughie! But at least there the hapless reader has some chance, 'cos the two clauses are in the "natural" order. I'd say it's still syntactically valid if they're reversed. Commas are for wusses, so: ***Till reeled the mind backward ran sentences***.

Comment: Well, it was a takeoff on Time Magazine's style of writing. Now someone needs to take on The New Yorker's style: everything you might want to know about X and ten times more, and the obscure word of the year, which must be worked into every issue. 1997 palimpsest; 2004 louche.